# how to measure cache usage of a cpp program?

Tags: c++, caching, benchmarking

I wonder if there is any tool to measure how much a cpp program benefits from caching (L1,L2,L3) ? For example, i) to measure how many requests could be handled directly by cache? ii) how many times the cache got flushed?

Comment: How about [cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg probably is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Valgrind** has a cache profiling utility called [cachegrind](http://www.valgrind.org/info/tools.html#cachegrind)

**Visual Studio** (from VS 2010 on) has an embedded profiler which shows information about cache hits and misses, accessible with the [CPU Counter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385772.aspx) options.